# Storing queries on backend access database

Tags: backend, ms-access-2013

I have built a split ms access 2013 database for a handful of users to share over our office LAN. I have been developing the front end forms and code and distributing by releasing new versions of the front end.

I would now like to build a reports menu but I would like to store the queries on the back end so I can make changes without releasing a new front-end version every time I update or add a report.

Is there a way to call a report or query in vba that is stored on the back end mdb? Would there by any significant performance degradation? If I understand how split access databases work , the queries are still processed on the local machine so it doesn't seem like it would make a difference. I have searched around the web but I have not found any questions on the topic. This leads to be believe I am on the wrong track. Thoughts?

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either save the queries in a separate file on the network share for the users to import from as needed.

A more polished method is to maintain a single frontend, then copy this to a network share when a new version is ready, and let the users download this whenever they launch the application from a shortcut. This way the distribution is fully automatic, and it even works in a Citrix environment.

The full description and a script (which you probably can reduce a little) can be found here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://rdsrc.us/dEJsQ0)

The crucial line where the local copy is opened is here:

```
' Run PPT.
If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
  Call RunApp(strAppLocalPath, False)
Else
  Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppLocalPath & vbCrLF & "could not be found.")    
End If
```

So to be sure get `strAppLocalPath` right.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the script a shot. A fully automated update solution does seem like the right way to go.

Comment: Question: The script copies the front end file to LOCALAPPDATA but then the shortcut opens the front end on the shared network location. I'd like the local version to open. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: IS there a way to upload my version of your script here? Sorry I'm a newb. >.<

Comment: Well, somehow you don't have the correct value in `strAppLocalPath`. See edited answer.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! This will save alot of time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Gustav said, I use the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) when specifying links to the BE from the FE.

For example:  \Server1\Directory\Subdirectory\Database_BE.mdb

I would place the FE in a serparte directory and then create a shortcut to the FE using UNC for the file location.

This takes care of the possibily of drive mappings changing or not existing.

Just my $0.02 worth and the benefits of being a SYSADMIN as well....lol